# compute with the values in table() function

Tags: r, contingency

I am new to R and stuck in computing the proportions of two values.

I got to this point with using the `table()` function

```
table(data$subscriptions, data$pickup)
```

The subscriptions data is divided into casual and registered users per station. Basically, I want to compute the proportion of casual users per station.

Should I be using `tapply()` to solve this?

[image: tab]

Thankful for any help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, make sure to provide a [mcve]. Images of your data do not help as the data cannot be copied and pasted into R code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a function `prop.table()` that is called on the `table` to turn counts into proportions. So in your case try something like this:

```
tab <- table(data$subscriptions, data$pickup)
prop.table(tab, 2)
```

Where `2` is a margin on which the proportions will be calculated. 2 means columns in your case.

Also see `help(prop.table)`